# Microsoft Excel replacing names with their ids

Tags: function, excel, replace, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to know how i can replace the names on columns G and H with their respective ids found on column B. I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010.
Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the file im referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use follwoing formula in `I1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,$A$1:$B$6,2,0)
```

and drag it to the right and down. Then you can select the result, copy it and paste in `G1:H6` with help of "Paste special" -> "values"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following subroutine.

```
Sub GetID(Rng As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim NameIDRng As Range
    Set NameIDRng = Range("A:B")
    For Each Cell In Rng
        On Error Resume Next
        Cell.Value = Application.VLookup(Cell.Value, NameIDRng, 2, False)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Call the above like so:

```
Sub Test()
    GetID Range("F1:G6")
End Sub
```

**Screenshot after running:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply even though I used Mr simoco's solution for I am merely a beginner with excel, yours seem to be working fine as well.